# Integral Elements form a Ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

Knowing that the monic polynomial and finitely-generated module definitions of integral elements over a commutative ring are equivalent, how can one prove that these elements form a ring?

Thanks.

Comment: If you read the solution at the linked question, it actually does it for integral elements too.

Comment: Which linked question?

Comment: This is *not* exactly the same question: the O.P. doesn't ask for *explicit polynomials* with roots the sum and product of two integral elements, but how to show these sum and product are integral elements.

Comment: @Bernard I don't contend that it's the same question, but I still think (as the template says) the question is answered there, and/or/in combination with at the two links in the problem statement.  It could also perhaps be a case of me picking a bad duplicate. I can't believe this question hasn't been asked here before...